# How to write a loop in R that selects an increasing percentage of rows per id group?

Tags: r, loops, dplyr

For dataframe `df`, I'd like to write a loop that selects a percentage of rows per `id` group, starting at 1% and increasing at 1% intervals all the way to 99% of the original `df`. The rows selected within a given `id`'s percentage sample should be random.

Starting with this dataframe:

```
df <- data.frame(id=rep(LETTERS, each=10)[1:50], fruit=sample(c("apple", "orange", "banana"), 50, TRUE))
```

I'd like to be able to get dataframes like the following, where a 10% sample would look like

```
df_10per <- data.frame(id=rep(LETTERS, each=1)[1:5], fruit=sample(c("apple", "orange", "banana"), 5, TRUE))
```

and a 50% sample might look like

```
df_50per <- data.frame(id=rep(LETTERS, each=5)[1:25], fruit=sample(c("apple", "orange", "banana"), 25, TRUE))
```

I've tried the following

```
require(dplyr)
    for (i in 1:100)
    {  i<-(i^-2)

  set.seed(123) 

  df_01per <-  df %>% 
    group_by(id) %>% 
    sample_frac('i',replace=TRUE) }
```

but get the error

```
size is not a numeric or integer vector
```

and I'm not sure I'm on the right track besides, although `dplyr` seems promising. Another problem with this code is that I don't know how to make a new `df` name for each new sample within the loop. Regarding that problem, a loop that adds a new column with the percentage sample (filling unsampled rows with `NA`) would also be an acceptable solution.

Thanks for taking a look.

Comment: `lapply(seq(.01,1,.01), function(i) df[1:(nrow(df)*i),])` you should also specify how you handle percentages that are not perfectly divisible.

Comment: plyr::ddply(df, "id", function(d) d[sample(1:nrow(d), 0.1 * nrow(d)), ])

Comment: @Pierre & @kitman0804 (and potential Googlers): Thanks to you both for your time/help. I ended up using the following, which works and gets me a random sample (Pierre's weren't random) and gets me that random sample within each id. (couldn't get kitman's to loop): `zz<-list()

for (i in 1:100)

  {
  
  i.2<-i/100
  df2 <- df %>% 
    group_by(id) %>%
    sample_frac(i.2,replace=TRUE)  
  df2
  zz[[i]]<-df2
  }
zz`   This worked for me, the commenters' might work for others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This did it for me:

```
zz<-list() for (i in 1:100) 
{ 
i.2<-i/100 
df2 <- df %>% 
  group_by(id) %>% 
  sample_frac(i.2,replace=TRUE) 
  df2 
  zz[[i]]<-df2 
} 
zz
```